# Virtualenv references global environment

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have 2 versions of python installed: 3.8.3 and 3.7.8

I created a virtualenv using 3.7 by `<exact path to 3.7 exe> -m virtualenv env` and activated it using `env\scripts\activate`. This activates the environment but `pip`, `python --version` and `which python` still refer to the global 3.8 installation. The only way to refer to the virtualenv python is by adding the path to the executable. This problem also messes with the plugins installed in VS code.

This is something I've been facing since July and I wonder if an update did this. I also have python installed on Ubuntu on WSL 2 via pyenv and use virtual environments created by pyenv-virtualenv. No problems there. I don't expect that to cause problems with the windows install but I've included the information just in case.

Edit: Older environments that I have successfully used without issues in the past have the same problem now.

Comment: I would recommend using pipenv instead of virtualenv.

Comment: @VaclavPelc I can do that. I still want to know what changed, though.

Comment: The standard and recommended one is `venv`.

Comment: @VPfB `venv` is a subset of virtualenv and is less performant IIRC.

Comment: @EdisonMaxwell Well, yes it is quite simple, but it is a part of standard library, i.e. widely used, well maintained and tested, etc.

Comment: @VPfB I'm working with video processing in real time using ML models. The documentation says that performance may be effected. I need all the performance I can get. I can definitely try `venv` and measure if there's actually any performance loss with what I'm trying to do.

I want to know why the behaviour of virtualenv changed and what it changed to or if I'm doing something wrong. I've had no problems earlier. Even `pipenv` mentioned earlier uses `virtualenv` so that will break too if `virtualenv` itself has a problem.

Comment: @EdisonMaxwell How virtual env works is described in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/ If a special file `pyvenv.cfg` exists relative to the python executable, it affects the Python's initialization. In your case an incorrect executable is started. That means (very probably) incorrect PATH, i.e. a problem with the activation script or its usage.

Comment: @VPfB The pyvenv.cfg file points to the python executable in the virtual environment. Even during creation the output message shows that its building from a the python version I want. Python --version still points to the global version after activating the environment.

Comment: @VPfB Same problem with `venv` as well. This has to be a bug in one of the libraries. I've even reinstalled python and am facing the same issue,

Comment: Older environments that I have successfully used without issues in the past have the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

## probably your path to virtual env is changed

After 2 years I just share my notion. Hopefully some find it useful.

In my experience it happened when I did a rename. I a directory name. Assume The path to my project is `/home/kasir/my django projects/my_weblog` and I change it like this: `/home/kasir/my_django_projects/my_weblog`. So I did this:

1. `rm -rf /home/kasir/my_django_projects/my_weblog/venv`
2. `cd /home/kasir/my_django_projects/my_weblog`
3. `virtualenv venv`
4. `source /home/kasir/my_django_projects/my_weblog/venv/bin/activate`
5. Now you can reinstall your packages in your new virtual env